Generate SAML assertion through privatekey in .net mvc
I need to generate SAML assertion (Base64-encoded assertion) through privetekey (.pem), userid, clientid, expireInMinutes and tokenurl parameters.
I have tried many way in .net mvc but it is not generating it.
I am following this link to generate assertion as need to pass in oAuth authentication into SuccessFactors https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SUCCESSFACTORS_PLATFORM/d599f15995d348a1b45ba5603e2aba9b/4e27e8f6ae2748ab9f23228dd6a31b06.html
